# re.sub matching multi-word expression with special signs

Tags: python, regex

Initially I used

```
re.sub(r'\b({0})\b'.format(T[i]), 'TARGET', j, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

but a couple of sentences have not been processed properly:

```
T[i] = '#dexter'
```

> finally starting the 5th season of #dexter.  see ya later, weekend!

and

```
T[i] = 'a$ap rocky'
```

> AHHH! My mom said yes for me to go the A$AP Rocky concert!! Nov 8th we
>   out! #EXCITE

For these two instances, T[i] are not being replaced by 'TARGET' as the hashtag sign appearing at the beginning of the first target and the dollar sign in the second target. I have also tried `r'\S*({0})\S*'` but still couldn't fix the second instance. Can you please help me specify the relevant regex expression? Thanks!

Comment: use lookarounds to check a  whitespace (or other characters like punctuation) or start and end of the string before and after the substring instead of word boundaries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The problem with `#dexter`

`\b` matches a word boundary, which is the empty string on either end of a sequence that would match `\w+`. However, `#` isn't matched by `\w+`, so the word boundary is on the *right* of the `#` instead of the *left*. One possible solution would be to use negative [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead of word boundaries:

```
r'(?<!\w)({0})(?!\w)'
```

### The problem with `a$ap rocky`

The `$` character has special meaning in regular expressions. You should pre-process your input strings before sticking them into the pattern. The [`re.escape`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.escape) function is designed exactly for this:

```
re.sub(r'\b({0})\b'.format(re.escape(T[i])), 'TARGET', j, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

### Putting the two together

```
re.sub(r'(?<!\w)({0})(?!\w)'.format(re.escape(T[i])), 'TARGET', j, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
```

Comment: Thanks. But `\S*({0})\S*` isn't strictly correct as e.g. `re.sub(r'\S*({0})\S*'.format(re.escape('#dexter')), '$T$', 'i love #dexter #dexteryeah', flags=re.IGNORECASE)` gives `'i love $T$ $T$'` rather than `'i love $T$ #dexteryeah'`. I want to make special signs such as @|#|$|% part of a word basically.

Comment: @Blue482 - `\S*` is basically worthless since it will _always_ match. For example, `abc#dexter` also matches. I had to take off earlier before I could suggest a better alternative, but I've updated my answer now.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks Mr. Wen!